# Importing functions that declare global variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, global-variables, python-import

**EDIT:** Alright, I pretty much figured it out (although it's not quite 100% what I wanted, it still works). It's the `execfile()` function, I can't believe I didn't know that was there.

I wasn't really sure how to phrase this question (and that's the reason my Google searches have turned up virtually nothing on this)... but here goes. I'm going to give a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. So let's say I have two files, `main.py` and `extra.py`. The latter looks something like this:

```
# extra.py

def setfoo(): # sets "foo" to 5 even if it is unassigned
    global foo
    foo = 5
```

So pretty straightforward if I run this in the console:

```
>>> setfoo()
>>> foo
5
```

Now let's head back over to `main.py`. I'll set up an import statement that imports everything from `extra.py`:

```
# main.py

from extra import *

setfoo()
print foo
```

Everything works fine up until the last line; however, when `main.py` tries to access `foo`, it doesn't recognize it since `foo` is actually stored under the file `extra.py`. If I import everything again after I run `setfoo()`, `foo` will be imported and everything will work fine. Like so:

```
# main.py

from extra import *

setfoo()
from extra import *
print foo
```

Alternatively, if I use a standard `import` statement instead of a `from...import` statement, there is no need to reimport everything, since the data from `extra.py` is being directly accessed rather than copied over. So this will work also:

```
# main.py

import extra

extra.setfoo()
print extra.foo
```

However, I really don't want to have to type out `extra.setfoo()` every time I want to run `setfoo()`, nor do I want to reimport `extra.py` each time I use said function. I would like to know if there is a workaround to this. Ideally, there would be a way to modify `extra.py` so that the code I set up in the original version of `main.py` works properly. (**EDIT:** It seems multiple people have misinterpreted this–I am willing to modify `extra.py`, it's `main.py` that I don't want to change, aside from the import statement at the top, to get this code to work.) If this isn't possible I would also consider using a different method of importing `extra.py` (I'm thinking something similar to PHP's `include` and `require` statements, in which the imported code is literally just copied and pasted into the file), but I would highly prefer that this modified import statement still be only one line of code, and not very lengthy. So in other words, using file handling plus an `exec` statement probably wouldn't be very convenient for this purpose.

Speaking of exec statements, I really don't care much at all how bad the coding practices I use are. I really just need a way to get this to work since the real version of this `extra.py` file is something I plan on using in almost all of my projects from now on, and I don't want to take up a lot of extra space in my code each time I import this file. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** It seems that a lot of people reading this aren't exactly clear on what I'm trying to accomplish, so here is the real version of my code. It's a syntax hack I put together to achieve "inline variable assignment". Here is the code (which works fine if you don't attempt to import it into another file):

```
class use_obj(object):
    def __rshift__(self, other): return other

def use(**kwargs):
    for var in kwargs: exec 'global ' + var + '; ' + var + ' = kwargs[var]'
    return use_obj()
```

The syntax looks like this:

```
print use(x = 5, y = 8) >> str(x) + " times " + str(y) + " equals " + str(x*y)
```

The code itself is pretty gross, but I've always wanted a way to perform inline variable assignment since I'm a big fan of inline if statements, list comprehensions, lambdas + `reduce()`, etc. The reason I can't simply have the function return the assigned variables is because `use(x = 5, y = 8)` is an expression (not a statement) that returns a weird object that I then shove into the code using the `>>` operator, and the weird object that the `use()` function returned magically disappears due to the way I set up the `__rshift__()` function.

I think the code would lose a lot of its beauty and novelty if it were to look like this:

```
print use(x = 5, y = 8) >> str(extras.x) + " times " + str(extras.y) + " equals " + str(extras.x*extras.y)
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're not setting `foo` while initializing `extra.py`? Otherwise a possible solution would be to set `foo = None`.

Comment: Well like I said, this is an oversimplified version of what I'm actually trying to do. The real version of the function sets multiple variables in the way that this one sets `foo`, and I have no way of knowing which variables it's going to set. So that's out the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First how you can import your variable without modifying extra.py, if really want too, 
You would have to take help of sys module for getting reference to foo in extra module.

```
import sys
from extra import *

print('1. Foo in globals ? {0}'.format('foo' in globals()))
setfoo()
print('2. Foo in globals ? {0}'.format('foo' in globals()))
# Check if extra has foo in it
print('2. Foo in extra ? {0}'.format(hasattr(sys.modules['extra'], 'foo')))
# Getting foo explicitly from extra module
foo = sys.modules['extra'].foo
print('3. Foo in globals ? {0}'.format('foo' in globals()))
print("Foo={0}".format(foo))
```

Output:

```
1. Foo in globals ? False
2. Foo in globals ? False
2. Foo in extra ? True
3. Foo in globals ? True
Foo=5
```

**Update for later usecase :**
Modifying extra.py which gets importer and updates its global variables,

```
# extra.py
import sys

def use(**kwargs):
    _mod = sys.modules['__main__']
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(_mod, k, v)
```

Now importing in any file remains same,

```
#myfile.py
from extra import *
print use(x = 5, y = 8), str(x) + " times " + str(y) + " equals " + str(x*y)
```

Output:

```
None 5 times 8 equals 40
```

`None` appears as use function returns nothing.

Note: It would be better if you choose better pythonic solution for your usecase, unless you are trying to have a little fun with python.

Refer for python scope rules:
[Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-scoping-rules?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: "Trying to have a little fun with Python" would be accurate. See my edit above–there's no way any of that stuff could remotely be considered "pythonic". Gimme a sec to try to process what you wrote above.

Comment: I'm not really going to try to comprehend what `globals()` does right now (I've never even heard of that function before), but it seems as if you've got it backwards. I can and want to modify `extra.py`, it's `main.py` that I don't want to touch.

Comment: Check update. You dont need to modify main.py in that case.

Comment: Didn't see your comment at first. I tried it, and the same issue is still happening. I would need to run `from extra import *` again after running the `use()` function to access the variables. But thanks for telling me about the `setattr()` function, that gets rid of that disgusting `exec` statement.

Comment: Is there something in the `sys.modules` that allows you to access the file that imported the code that is currently being run?

Comment: Wait, I'm an idiot, it did work. Nevermind then. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Lastly, I'm assuming the name `_mod` doesn't have any significance, just an arbitrary variable name... right? Or does it have a specific purpose?

Comment: No. It is just variable name. No specific purpose here to start name with `_`. I sometimes tend to us `_` for temporary/private variables in function.

Comment: Can you please mark answer correct if it helps you ?

Comment: Oh yeah sure, didn't realize. New to this site.

Answer (score 0):

Modules have namespaces which are variable names bound to objects. When you do `from extra import *`, you take the objects found in `extra`'s namespace and bind them to new variables in the new module. If `setfoo` has never been called, then `extra` doesn't have a variable called `foo` and there is nothing to bind in the new module namespace.

Had `setfoo` been called, then `from extra import *` would have found it. But things can still be funky. Suppose some assignment sets `extra.foo` to `42`. Well, the other module namespace doesn't know about that, so in the other module, `foo` would still be `5` but `extra.foo` would be `42`.

Always keep in mind the difference between an object and the things that may be referencing the object at any given time. Objects have no idea which variables or containers happen to reference them (though they do keep a count of the number of references). If a variable or container is rebound to a different object, it doesn't change the binding of other variables or containers.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I learned from a bit of Googling around. Do you know if there's any way that `extra.py` can set variables in the namespace of whatever file imported it (`main.py` in this case)? I think that would solve my problem.

Comment: You can't do that but you can put `extra` inside its own container (e.g., `my_config = { 'foo':5 }`. However, a better solution is to not do `from extra import *`. Had you just done `import extra` and referenced the variable as `extra.foo` everywhere, everyone would be referencing the same object in the `extra` namespace. That is, modules are containers so just keep referencing them.

Comment: I don't think that's an option, sadly. It's pretty much a requirement that I access it as `foo` and not `extra.foo`. Putting it in a container like a dictionary also wouldn't accomplish what I am trying to do.

Comment: I once had a client who demanded that programs I delivered to him for Windows not have a file extension like ".exe". But Windows requires extensions on runnable files. I had to drop him as a client. I don't know enough about your requirements but on the face of it, it seems equally idiotic. The language doesn't work that way.

Comment: The whole thing is purposely idiotic, it's a way for me to write blocks of code in one line that I really should be writing in multiple lines, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing details, one possible solution would be to return `foo` in `extra.py setfoo()` function instead of declaring as a global variable.

Then declare global `foo` in main.py and feed in value from external function `setfoo()`

Here is the setup

```
#extra.py

def setfoo(): # sets "foo" to 5 even if it is unassigned
    #global foo
    foo = 5
    return foo

#main.py

from extra import setfoo

global foo

foo = setfoo()
print foo
```

**Result:**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
5
>>>
```

**EDIT - 1**
OK, take-2 at this problem.

I don't endorse it, but if there is a specific need, If you add a variable to the `__builtin__` module, it will be accessible as a global from any other module as long as it includes `__builtin__` .

```
#extra.py

import __builtin__

def setfoo(): # sets "foo" to 5 even if it is unassigned
    global foo
    __builtin__.foo = 5


#main.py

from extra import *
setfoo()
print foo
```

Output:

```
>>> 
5
>>>
```

Comment: Hate to say it but modifying the code in `main.py` is pretty much out of the question, unless I'm only modifying the way it is imported. This is actually for a really weird syntax "hack" I'm working on, so it has very specific needs and I can't use something like `foo = setfoo()` since I need that line of code to be an expression, not a statement.

Comment: if you can modify `extra,py` a little, pls see modified solution above.

Comment: This seems to be taking a bit to far, and if I were to do this, my code wouldn't work if I were to send it to someone else. Just to make it clear, I _can_ modify `extra.py` and that was the main aim of my question, it's `main.py` that I don't want to have to change to get this code to work.

Comment: you are not changing `main.py` with new solution, just `extra.py`